# Is it ok to use Unoffical Airplay protocol?

Tags: iphone, airplay

I have come across this link
http://nto.github.com/AirPlay.html while searching for ways to implement Airplay. I dont have an apple tv so I was testing using Airserver. I could achieve the image sharing via the unofficial protocol.
My question is that if I put up an application like this to iTunes, will it be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

recently, lots of airplay hack apps have been removed from the AppStore:

https://www.google.es/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=airplay+removed+appstore

Comment: So if I use the private protocol, it gets rejected. If I use MPVolumeView, it doesnt show the mirroring option. How do I program it to show application content? I think I will have to rely on the system provided button for the device.

Comment: So that means I cannot get the mirroring button in the application and put up mirroring?

Comment: MPVolumeView is only to change the audio route. You cannot activate airplay mirroring by code: the user has to do it by himself. Once airplay mirroring is on, your app can access the second UIScreen object to add its own content

Answer (score 0):

**IF** it's an open-source project then should be fine, otherwise Apple doesn't allow private protocol - frameworks.